# PHP ratchet/pawl return data instead of printing

Tags: php, sockets, async-await

The following script allows to only print data instead of returning ( $msg ), I have embedded it to a controller function but unable to return the response back

```
<?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    \Ratchet\Client\connect('wss://echo.websocket.org:443')->then(function($conn) {
        $conn->on('message', function($msg) use ($conn) {
            echo "Received: {$msg}\n"; // NEED TO RETURN THIS INSTEAD OF PRINTING
            $conn->close();
        });

        $conn->send('Hello World!');
    }, function ($e) {
        echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```php
<?php
$message = null;
\Ratchet\Client\connect('wss://echo.websocket.org:443')->then(function($conn) use (&$message) {
     $conn->on('message', function($msg) use ($conn, &$message) {
        $conn->close();
        $message = "Received: {$msg}\n";
     });
     $conn->send('Hello World!');
}, function ($e) use (&$message) {
     $message = "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
});
echo $message;
```

```php
$message = "old message";
(function() use (&$message) {
    (function() use(&$message) {
        $message = "new message";
    })();
})();
echo $message; // returns "new message"
```

Comment: tried second example also with same result, i think it is something to do with the asyc await